# Import Swift framework in Swift: "Use of undeclared type 'MyCustomView'"

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift

I have a Swift project where I added a framework target with a custom subclass of `UIView` so I can use the new live view in Interface Builder within Xcode 6. But when I try to add an `@IBOutlet` in my `UIViewController` subclass in my project I get a **"Use of undeclared type 'MyCustomView'"** error and I can't build my project.

Here's my code from the UIViewController subclass:

```
import UIKit
import MyCustomFramework


class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myCustomView: MyCustomView?

}
```

And this is what 'MyCustomView.swift' within the 'MyCustomFramework' target looks like:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class MyCustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView?

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I forgot? Did I import it in a wrong way? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should mark the class as `public` since it is part of different framework module

```
@IBDesignable public class MyCustomView: UIView {

}
```

By default classes and methods will be at `internal` access level. If you want to use that out side of that target you should mark it as public. Then only it will be the part of public interface(visible to outside of target)

Comment: I think it's a good idea to always read the complete Release Notes for every single beta update from Apple. This feature was added via update and I didn't notice the change. Thank you for the hint anyways! :)

Comment: I'm also experiencing problems still, but mine isn't framework code its my own code...

Comment: I got mine working now, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s gives the solution. Basically somehow the build phases got messed up, so if your code is internal and you found this question, this should help.

Comment: Looked for an hour for this. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error after importing my custom framework A inside another project B, even all my classes were public.

I solved it by changing the Building settings of my custom framework A at Build Active Architecture only to No instead of Yes, then clean compile, and reimport the framework again after deleting the old one.

Then everything compiled successfully.