# prepareForSegue (ViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, undefined, viewcontroller

Then i try to sent data from one view to another

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "varView" {
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController

        var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

        viewController.varView = self.exams[indexPath.row]

    }

}
```

I get an error at witch says that ViewController is a undeclared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s

Comment: "as ViewController" or "as UIViewController" ? what is the class ViewController?

Comment: Please give more details (class name of the current view controller, class name of the destination view controller, ...).

Comment: i have fixed the error. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `prepareForSegue` you can directly call `viewController` from storyboard and pass the data

declare variable in the file you want to pass the data and `#import` the header file in which you want to pass the data.

```
#import "file.h"

file *data = [[file alloc]init];
data.index = add_index;
```

then navigate as follow...

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.navigationController;
UIViewController *createEvent = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerID"];

[navigationController pushViewController:createEvent animated:YES];
```