# Swift: Use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, protocols

I'm implementing a class but I'm getting this error:

> Use of undeclared type 'myProtocol'

Here is my code:

```
class LocalContactService: myProtocol{
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Have you declared a protocol "myProtocol"? If so, please show us the declaration. If not, I would recommend you to read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 6):

i had the same error .in my case i found accidentally that i added my swift files into "copy bundle resource" in "build phase" i removed all swift file except assets then everything worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the issue is caused when the classes in question do not belong to the same targets, usually the test target is missing. Just make sure the following check boxes are ticked. you can refer to original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30737191/3992606

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue! Every time this is so insanely unexpected. I am hopping between kotlin and swift all the time and I don't expect such errors from not marking the unit tests. Imo very unintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you've never defined `myProtocol`. Or if you have, maybe it's out of scope in the `LocalContactService` class

Comment: How do I define the protocol?

Comment: Here are some examples: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html  A basic definition (without any useful content) would be `protocol myProtocol {}`

Comment: This was exactly my problem! And I had it on the same file, so it wasn't obvious.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when someone pushed changes that they made to the `project.pbxproj` file.

Select the file hit `delete` and choose the option to `Remove Reference`

Add the file back to the project, clean (cmd + shift + k), and rebuild

Comment: I ran into this issue while working through this SwiftUI tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input and following the steps you provided fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `myProtocol` class, and on the right side (If you are using XCode), click the Tests of your class. This is what I mean.

["Use of undeclared type" in Swift, even though type is internal, and exists in same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s)

Answer (score 1):

I my case I had to clean the build folder, close the project, run `pod install`, and then the issue disappeared.