# SugarRecord cocoa pods undeclared type issue

Tags: ios, swift, sugarrecord

I have found [SugarRecord](https://github.com/pepibumur/SugarRecord) library as an alternative to MagicalRecord I use in Objective-C.

My project uses Swift as main language. I've added SugarRecord library via cocoa pods and now when I try to implement this code:

```
func coreDataStorage() -> CoreDataDefaultStorage {
    let store = CoreData.Store.Named("posts-db")
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: CoreDataDefaultStorageTests.classForCoder())
    let model = CoreData.ObjectModel.Merged([bundle])
    let defaultStorage = try! CoreDataDefaultStorage(store: store, model: model)

    return defaultStorage
  }
```

Xcode throws erros here:
/Users/amatrosov/Documents/projects/Project-Name/Project-Name/NewProgramService.swift:18:29: Use of undeclared type 'CoreDataDefaultStorage'

Comment: see once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, not sure I understood that problem and answers, maybe you have another examples, thanks!

Comment: Hey Alexandre, did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @PedroPiñeraBuendia, yea I answered on my question, this is should help.

Answer (score 0):

I used this `pod "SugarRecord/CoreData"` you can also use another if you need more frameworks.

In file that I want to use some SugarRecord functions I added these lines:

```
import SugarRecord
import CoreData
```