# Xcode showing error with embedded framework but it compiles well

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app with a custom Swift framework that is used to share business rules across different plateform. Every time I try to use a class from this framework, Xcode is showing me errors but everything compiles well.
It also preventing me from using autocompletion regarding this framework.

I already try cleaning and deleting derived data but without any results.

My framework is included in my main projet via a submodule and manually linked on my main project.

Any thoughts on this ?

[image]

Comment: are you added your framework in embedded binaries

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Yes, it's done

Comment: If it compiles and works ok, try cleaning your project (shortcut CMD + Shift + K) and then build it once again

Comment: @mcgtrt I already try several times, along with deleting derived data

Comment: what is your xcode version ?

Comment: Also make sure the file is part of the framework target.

Comment: @MohamedRaffi 9.3.1

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Just checked, every file is part of the framework target

Comment: see this once may be it he;ps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s

Comment: are you working with multiple targets ?

Comment: I had a similar problem in Obj-C project and setting `Precompile Prefix Header` to `No` in the build settings was helpful to me. Dunno if it would work for Swift.

Comment: @MohamedRaffi Yes I have multiple targets

Comment: @mcgtrt already tried without results unfortunatly

Comment: @Anbu.karthik just checked the link, nothing relevant for me unfortunatly

Comment: oh sorry, i unable to help you

Comment: try to set the same iOS deployment target values for the main app target  & Pods targets.

Comment: @MohamedRaffi It is the same deployment target already. I forgot to specify that that framework is not embedded via Cocoapods but via a submodule

Comment: Do you have any classes with same name ?

Comment: Check your Compile Sources in Build Phases. May be same classes added twice.

Comment: @MohamedRaffi Not for the example I put on my post. However I do have other class that has same name but I'm always prefixing thoses classes with the framework name, i.e `BusinessRulesKit.Job`. And I just checked, everything is good in Compile Sources

Comment: Don't think this is a solution, but just in case, did you declare your class 'BusinessRules' as public?

Answer (score 1):

My custom Swift framework class:

```
public class Myfile {
    public func textmethod(){
        print("The value of textmethod")
    }
}
```

Imported framework to the project
[image]

My ViewController file:

```
import MyFrameWork

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let log = Myfile()
        log.textmethod()
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing

Comment: Can u access the classname now??

Comment: No I mean, this is what I'm doing in the first place

Comment: Have you gave Your file name and class name same in framework? and also check have you imported in your VC class?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the framework's search path. I assume its now set for the target but not for the project (or incorrectly set on the project). You can set it only for the project and let Xcode handle target path.

> Xcode has a separate compilation process for computing autocomplete references, from the compilation process for actually building your project. If you accidentally set the framework search path for your target instead of the project as a whole, your project will seem to build fine.
>   https://medium.com/@_achou/one-weird-trick-to-fix-autocomplete-in-xcode-9f19dc856944

*Solution 1:* Fix framework search path in *Project - Build Settings.*

*Solution 2:* Remove the framework from your project, head to *Targets - Build Phase - Embeded Frameworks*, click on **+ (add)** and then **Add Other** and find it in your directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your framework then CMD+B close XCODE open it again add the framework again and CMD+B. By the way have you moved your project folder recently??

[image: Try this]

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same problem recently. The solution I found that I had to run the app in the simulator for then the xCode to start recognizing the framework and hence to get the autocomplete feature..

Give it a try..!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using git in this project? As odd as it may sound, I've resolved similar issues by committing the current code.

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem recently. I solved it by setting the framework and header search path to non-recursive in the project scope and pointing directly to the correct directory without subfolders. My target then inherits the search paths from the project.